# Node.js <Class> is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting "HttpHandlers is not a constructor" error when trying to instantiate that class using "new".

Class being instantiated (../lib/restifyHandlers/HttpHandlers):

```
var config = require('config');
module.exports.config = config;

var util = require('util');
var _ = require('underscore');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var HttpHandlers  = function(eventHandlers) {
    var _self = this;
    this.name = "HttpHandlers";
    if (!(this instanceof HttpHandlers)) {
        return new HttpHandlers(eventHandlers);
    }
}

util.inherits(HttpHandlers, EventEmitter);

HttpHandlers.prototype.extractHttpHandlersRequest = function(req, res, next) {
    var _self = this;
    req.locals = {};
    res.locals = {};

}
module.exports.HttpHandlers = HttpHandlers;
```

Code making the call:

```
var HttpHandlers = require('../lib/restifyHandlers/HttpHandlers');
var obj = new HttpHandlers(oneRouteConfig.eventHandlers);
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-09-10T23:44:41.571-04:00 - [31merror[39m: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 03:44:41 GMT Worker #master: exiting from error:  TypeError: HttpHandlers is not a constructor 
TypeError: HttpHandlers is not a constructor
    at setupRestifyRoute (/usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/lib/router.js:78:14)
    at Router.setup_routes (/usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/lib/router.js:40:3)
    at /usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/bin/server.js:222:14
    at initialize (/usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/bin/server.js:38:9)
    at setup_server (/usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/bin/server.js:107:4)
    at /usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/bin/server.js:275:4
    at /usr/apps/das/src/myrepo/nodejs/myapp/node_modules/temp/lib/temp.js:231:7
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

Comment: No need to new it. `HttpHandlers(oneRouteConfig.eventHandlers);` should just work fine.

Comment: @vijayst, I tried that and the error I get then is "HttpHandlers is not a function"

Comment: Why do you need to reexport the config in line 2 ? Just use `module.exports = HttpHandlers` to export the and you ll be fine

Comment: This error also occurs when `new` is called on a defined class but the `module.exports = HttpHandlers;` is missing.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you assigned this:

```
exports.HttpHandlers = HttpHandlers;
```

You would need to match that with this:

```
var HttpHandlers = require('../lib/restifyHandlers/HttpHandlers').HttpHandlers;
```

---

You are assigning a property of your module to be `.HttpHandlers`, not assigning the whole module so if you want that property, you have to reference the property.  If you want it to work the other way, you could change to this:

```
exports = HttpHandlers;
```

And, then your `require()` could work the way you are doing it like this:

```
var HttpHandlers = require('../lib/restifyHandlers/HttpHandlers');
```

Comment: Thanks bro!! Your answer helped saved my time.

Comment: This answer helped me. In a truffle/mocha test I'm working with, I needed to do: `const MyClass = require('@alias/MyClass').default` because I'm exporting `export default class MyClass {}`

Comment: Thanks @Gus! Exactly my problem, going now for hours, just solved thanks to your hint!

Comment: This had also stumped me for the last hour or so. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I got this error when calling `new ClassName();` and it was caused in the ClassName class by missing off the "module." from `module.exports = ClassName`

Just in case someone else is as daft as me...

Comment: my mistake was missing the s on exports: module.export = ClassName

Answer (score 7):

I got this error because I had some cyclic import. So the class was undefined..

If it can help someone else !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, something weird was being done with the exports from the library I was using. I recommend trying to `console.log()` (or `debugger;`) whatever you're `require()`ing and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a simple dumb issue

I used

```
module.exports = {classname}
```

instead it should be

```
module.exports = classname
```