# Cant start my server when moving everything to 1 file

Tags: javascript, node.js

at the moment I have an app.js file and a server.js file. The server runs fine when I run 'node app.js' in CMD but I'm trying to put everything in the server.js file.

App.js:

```
var Server = require('./server.js').Server;

var server = new Server();
server.initialise(8080);
```

Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var events = require('events');
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();

exports.Server = Server = function() {

    this.userId = 1;
};

Server.prototype.initialise = function(port) {

    this.server = http.createServer(app);

    app.use(express.static('public'));

    this.server.listen(port);
    this.startSockets();
    this.em = new events();

    console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
};
```

So I've tried moving the last 2 lines of app.js to the server but I'm getting the error that Server isnt a constructer. I've tried

```
var Server = this;
```

I've also tried

```
this.initialise(8080);
```

Nothing seems to work

Comment: `new Server().initialise(8080);`... just like you call it in the other file.

Comment: im getting the error that Server is not defined

Comment: `console.log(require('./server.js'))` ...

Comment: Sorry, didn't really read it carefully. `new exports.Server().initialise(8080);`. I'd change the declaration to make the access unnecessary, but that's just me.

Comment: its saying exports.Server is not a constructor :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js <Class> is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432687/node-js-class-is-not-a-constructor)

Comment: I just copied everything from your second code block, then the last 2 lines from your top code block and the only error I got was `this.startSockets()` is not defined (i'd expect this).  I'm using the latest LTS release of node (8.11.1).  You might want to double check what you copied.

Comment: really? im on the exact same node version and im getting the 'Server' is not a constructor error